# Frenet-Serret formula proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Prove that $$\textbf{r}''' = [s'''-\kappa^2(s')^3]\textbf{ T } + [3\kappa s's''+\kappa'(s')^2]\textbf{ N }+\kappa \hspace{1mm}\tau (s')^3\textbf{B}.$$

What is $\tau$, I can't figure that part out.

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Tau is torsion?

Comment: what is the formula

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve

Comment: thanks for that, but that didn't help much

Answer (score 1):

I will keep updating, this is where I am now .

We know that $$\textbf{T} = \dfrac{\textbf{r}'}{\left| \textbf{r}'\right|}$$

$$\textbf{r}' = \left| \textbf{r}'\right|\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}$$

$\color{red}{\text{Note that}}$ $|\textbf{r}'| = s'$

$$\textbf{r}' =s'\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}$$

Differentiate both sides

$$\textbf{r}'' =s''\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}+s'\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}' \rightarrow \textbf{(1)}$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Recall that}}$ $$\kappa = \dfrac{\left|\textbf{T}' \right|}{\left|\textbf{r}' \right|}$$

$$\kappa = \dfrac{\left|\textbf{T}' \right|}{s'}$$

$$s'\kappa = \left|\textbf{T}' \right| \rightarrow \textbf{(2)}$$

We Also know that $$\textbf{N} = \dfrac{\textbf{T}'}{\left|\textbf{T}' \right|}$$

Use Eqn $\textbf{(2)}$

$$\textbf{N} = \dfrac{\textbf{T}'}{s' \kappa}$$

$$\textbf{N } s' \kappa = \textbf{T}'$$

Substitute this in Eqn $\textbf{(1)}$, To get

$$\textbf{r}'' =s''\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}+s'\hspace{1mm}\left(\textbf{N }\kappa s' \right) $$

$$\textbf{r}'' =s''\hspace{1mm}\textbf{T}+\kappa \left(s'\right)^2 \hspace{1mm}\textbf{N } $$

Differentiate

$$\textbf{r}''' = \left[s'''\textbf{ T } +s''\textbf{ T }'  \right]+ \left[ \kappa' \left(s' \right)^2\textbf{ N}+2\kappa s's'' \textbf{ N}+\kappa \left(s' \right)^2\textbf{ N}'\right]$$

Rearrange the terms  $$\textbf{r}''' = \left[s'''\right]\textbf{ T }  + \left[ \kappa' \left(s' \right)^2+2\kappa s's''\right] \textbf{ N}+\kappa \left(s' \right)^2\textbf{ N}'+s''\textbf{ T }' $$

I am stuck now

Comment: can someone putin the colors, they are nor working

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that, for a generic function $f$,
$$
f'=\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}=s'\frac{df}{ds}
$$
so that
$$
\mathbf{N}'=s'\frac{d\mathbf{N}}{ds}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{N}}{ds}=-\kappa\mathbf{T}+\tau\mathbf{B}
$$
see [Frenet-Serret formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).

Also, your $\kappa'$ is indeed $\frac{d\kappa}{dt}$, while in the formula to prove it is intended as $\frac{d\kappa}{ds}$.

Comment: thanks, I finished it, we can continue from the formula you gave, I wont update, since it will get very lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Actually its easy. You just need to start with an equation r'= s' t and take its two further derivaties w.r.t s, then you just need to use all the three Ferent-Serret equations in the whole process, wherever required.

Note: there will be a use of chain rule in the initial process.